# 404 resolving view in spring servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring (4) MVC servlet running on Tomcat 8 in Eclipse. When I start tomcat, there are no errors in the console and all the correct request mappings for my controllers are logged. If I try to access `localhost:8080/app/login` my controller method executes (checked via debugging), but I get a 404 page with the following:

> message /app/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

My project has the following directory structure:

```
project-root
 |-src
 |-WebContent
    |-WEB-INF
       |-jsp
          |-login.jsp
```

My configuration class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp").viewClass(JstlView.class);
    }
    //Other stuff
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class AuthnRequestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
    //Other stuff
}
```

The application was working fine in the past, but I was screwing around with my workspace/projects working on something else, and am unable to get this working again now that I'm coming back to it.

Comment: Do you have another page? When you request others are they behave same?

Comment: can you try putting the jsp folder in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`

Comment: @erhun Yes, I have one other page and it behaves exactly the same (controller method executes, 404 error)

Comment: @MichellePlease check redflar3 sugesstion, i agree that it is a path issue.

Comment: What url pattern is your `DispatcherServlet` mapped with?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `/`

Comment: Do you have any log framework within your application like log4j ? Consider in adding it if not and set it to debug on the servlet classes then you will see exactly what it is doing!

Comment: @redflar3 So, that did the trick (if you could post that as an answer, that'd be great), although now I'm curious as to what was making it work with `WebContent` before. Eclipse settings that got blown away when I was messing around with my projects, I guess?

Comment: `root/WebContent` is a fine place to put your jsps. You just need to include it in your project's Deployment Assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, By default in a maven war project the jsp files are expected under `/src/main/resources/`. Since you have given a jsp file prefix of `/WEB-INF/jsp/` in your config, please try moving the jsp files to the below location.

`/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/`

Assumptions:

- a mapping to `root/WebContent` is not provided in Web deployment assembly.
- a mapping to `/src/main/webapp` is present in Web deployment assembly.
- your eclipse is using `maven war plugin`